# Unknown file extension ".ts" cypress.config.ts on CI

Tags: cypress

When I run `npm run cypress:run` in my GitLab CI env I get the error:

> Your configFile is invalid: /**/WebApp/cypress.config.ts
> It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:
> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /**/WebApp/cypress.config.ts

```yaml
test:cypress:
  image:
    name: cypress/included:10.3.1-typescript
    entrypoint: ['']
  stage: test
  script:
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    - cd WebApp
    - npm run cypress:run
  rules:
    - *branch
```

If I run `npm run cypress:run` from the `WebApp` folder (where `cypress.config.ts` is in the root) locally I have no issue. Also no issues when I do an `npx cypress:run`

However, if I run `npx cypress run --config-file WebApp/cypress.config.ts` from the parent folder locally I do get the error:

> Unknown file extension ".ts"

Any ideas why locally Cypress is working but on the CI the config file is incorrect?

Answer (score 9):

I updated [this github issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/issues/432) with some more information.

This will be because you have typescript installed globally on your machine so it will work ok locally but not in CI.

Essentially typescript **has** to be in the folder from where the cypress command is run for it to detect typescript properly.

I went with:

```
  script:
      - npm install --global serve
      - serve ./build --listen 3000 &
      - rm package*
      - npm install @percy/cypress typescript
      - npm install --global @percy/cli
      - percy exec --verbose -- cypress run
```

Just installing the bare minimum to run the e2e tests **./build** is an artifact from another run and [percy](https://percy.io/) is really great if you have not used it before.

Comment: Installing typescript with `npm install @percy/cypress typescript` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This still seems to be an issues today for LTS 10.10.0

Changing the fresh install cypress.config.ts -> cypress.config.js
and use require like so proved successful.

```
module.exports = require('cypress').defineConfig({  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "create-react-app",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all different ways suggested in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22071) that
user18025789 linked, but nothing helped. Then I tried switching the config file from `.ts` to `cypress.config.js` and it started to work (syntax needed to be updated to JavaScript as well). I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, I fixed mine by adding `"typescript": "~4.4.4"` inside my package.json dependencies.

I am using cypress `v12.10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing a `node_modules` directory, so I had to restore npm packages by running `npm ci` (or `npm install`).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's about the version. This might be hepful [GitHub](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22071)

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue because Typescript was not installed in my Cypress container. When ts-node doesn't have access to typescript, it's require behaves like the native "require", which is why you're seeing the error.

I don't know enough about your specific setup to recommend a solution, but for me I was able to run `npm i` and mount the volume in the cypress container before running the tests. Another option could be to create a new Dockerfile to extend the base Cypress image with typescript included in the build.

Answer (score -1):

If working on a monorepo and mounting only the app/package folder to test into the cypress docker image, not all dependencies are available within this directory.

To fix this mounting, the whole workspace does the job:

```yaml
cypress:
    image: cypress/included:10.11.0
    # …
    working_dir: /workspace/app
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace
```

Answer (score -1):

I am late here, i had similar issue. The `del` package to delete passed videos  was the culprit for me. In the CI environment, it requested to install the `del` package separately, but in my `cypress.config.ts`, i was directly able to import del package which was served from third party.

I wanted to install the exact `del` package in my case and that solved the problem. Del package has its limitations, rimraf solved my issue.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you solve your issue?

Comment: @cksanjose - instead of `del` npm package, use `rimraf` package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

Answer (score -2):

I started facing this issue, suddenly, 
My solution was
`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
`npm i`
 I already had the cypress.config.ts file, so cypress test runner picked it up, when I ran
`npx cypress open`